# String parsing in Python, regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have text that is formatted as follows

> |relevant text| followed by |variable number of white spaces| followed by |relevant text (a
> folder path containing white spaces| followed by |variable number of white spaces| followed  by |not relevant text|

My goal is to retreive the two relevant text but I have no experience in dealing with regular expressions (I believe this is what I should use?)

Thanks in advance! :)

For example:

> ```
> 68465d1wd        C:\nice\ pro   g  ram   files\path.html          d   d5 d   w4d   w5 d   4wd46
> ```

I would want to retreive

> foo = 68465d1wd
>
> bar = path.html

Comment: can you put some example code? seems like you can use split() to do that

Comment: What resource are you using for your regex information? The techniques you need are all pretty straightforward.  Use parentheses for the relevant text and ` *` for variable white space. You just need to figure out how to separate your folder path from the non-relevant text.

Comment: @Twissell edited in an example

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I have no experience in using regex.

Comment: Your example is helpful, but you still have the problem of terminating the filename and distinguishing it from the irrelevant text that follows.  Is the irrelevant text always present and does it always contain no spaces?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin the irrelevant text that follows is always present and is always separated by at least one space. It also contains lots of spaces. A better example would've been " w  d dwww   45 1 " instead of "dw6d5w4dw5d4wd46"

Comment: Then you've got a problem, unless you know some constraints about the filename itself. Before you can fashion a regex, you need to figure how to reliably distinguish the filename from the fields that precede and follow it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin How about knowing that the file necessarily has a .html or .php extension, would that help?

Comment: Yes, that would do it. I'll update my answer below, though I'm not sure why it was downvoted and therefore not sure how I can address whatever problem someone saw with it.

Comment: @Peter I think you can ignore the downvoter, I also got hit for no good reason (unless that was you :-))

Comment: @Pi, what else _can_ appear in the irrelevant text? Punctuation?Backslashes? Other filenames?

Comment: Are you sure these are multiple spaces and not tabs, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields are separated by *at least* two spaces, this should do it:

```
import re
foo, bar, _irrelevant = re.split(r"\s{2,}",  line)
```

**Edit:** The above solution no longer works for the revised answer. If (as I gather from your comments) the filename always has a `.php` or `.htm[l]` extension, *and* there's always a path before the final filename, you can try your luck with the following:

```
foo, rest = re.split(r"\s{2,}",  line, 1)
bar = re.search(r"[^\\]*\.(?:php|html?)\b", rest).group(0)
```

This will give you everything after the last backslash preceding `.php`, `.htm` or `.html`. Basically there's a regexp for everything, but you need to figure out what your data looks like.

Comment: What if the filename contains two or more spaces in it?

Comment: here's a solution: `foo, bar = (re.split(r"\s{2,}",  line)[0], re.split(r"\s{2,}",  line)[-2])`

Comment: Two or more _adjacent_ spaces in the filename? Then either the input is ambiguous, or there are other constraints we can leverage (e.g., if the filename always has an extension, the irrelevant text never contains backslashes, etc.))

Comment: @Alexis, yes, as far as I know, if one space is allowed in a filename, then two adjacent spaces are allowed, although obviously that would be rare. BTW, it wasn't me who downvoted your answer. :-)

Comment: They're allowed, sure, but how often does this happen? I think the OP needs to tell us what the data _actually_ looks like.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = '''68465d1wd        C:\nice\ program files\path.html          dw6d5w4dw5d4wd46'''
>>> re.split(r'\s{2,}', data)
['68465d1wd', 'C:\nice\\ program files\\path.html', 'dw6d5w4dw5d4wd46']
>>> foo, bar = re.split(r'\s{2,}', data)[:2]
>>> foo
'68465d1wd'
>>> bar
'C:\nice\\ program files\\path.html'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(bar)
'path.html'
```

Without regular expression:

```
>>> foo, rest = data.split(' ', 1)
>>> bar, rest = rest.lstrip().split('  ', 1)
>>> foo
'68465d1wd'
>>> bar
'C:\nice\\ program files\\path.html'
>>> os.path.basename(bar)
'path.html'
```